# Enlightenment (E17) not opening settings windows or click menu

Tags: gdm, enlightenment

I cannot open any settings windows and cannot access the menu be clicking on an empty part of the desktop on enlightenment installed on Arch. What could be the problem?

I'm running GDM for a desktop manager.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I just did a radical edit of your post, feel free to roll back (click on the "edited X seconds ago" link to see how). Bear in mind, that thanks are not necessary here, the way to thank people is by upvoting and/or accepting good answers. The rest of the information you gave did not help us understand your question and in fact distracted from it so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running nautilus file manager or another file manager which overlays the viewable desktop. I've ran into this problem when using Openbox. Disable nautilus or the file manager causing the problem and that should fix the issue.